# ffmpeg atempo filter not working

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

When I run the following:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter:a "atempo=2.0" -vn output.mp3
```

I expect output.mp3 to be twice as fast (and half the length) of input.mp3, but it is exactly the same speed and length than the input.mp3. In fact, it produces exactly the same file as when `-filter:a "atempo=2.0"` are not used. I have also tested it on a wav output.

I see two similar warning in the output (`Truncating packet of size 1024 to 597`), but nothing severe.

How do I get the filter to work?

**edit**

Here is the output from ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i "1-02 Ein Junge überlebt.mp3" -filter:a "atempo=2.0"  -vn "converted/music.mp3"
ffmpeg version 0.10.12-7:0.10.12-1~saucy1 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 26 2014 09:54:16 with gcc 4.8.1
  configuration: --arch=amd64 --disable-stripping --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='7:0.10.12-1~saucy1' --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil      51. 35.100 / 51. 35.100
  libavcodec     53. 61.100 / 53. 61.100
  libavformat    53. 32.100 / 53. 32.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 61.100 /  2. 61.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
[mp3 @ 0x216f740] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5004000
Input #0, mp3, from '1-02 Ein Junge überlebt.mp3':
  Duration: 00:05:22.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 57 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 32000 Hz, mono, s16, 56 kb/s
File 'converted/music.mp3' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, mp3, to 'converted/music.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf53.32.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 32000 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 -> libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Truncating packet of size 1024 to 597ate= 128.0kbits/s    
Truncating packet of size 1024 to 1
size=    5036kB time=00:05:22.27 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:5036kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.011849%
```

Comment: Please include the complete console output from your command.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I added the necessary output as an edit. I did somehow fix this problem, by using the Windows binaries of ffmpeg under wine, so I guess my ffmpeg was just buggy.

Comment: You should post this as an answer to help others with the same issue. And yeah, the 0.10 series is a little old. We're at 2.5 already.

Comment: @slhck I have written it as an answered as you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These type of problems seems to be fixable by updating ffmpeg, but I am paranoid about updating/changing anything codecs-wise on my system and have decided to rather use the windows binaries of ffmpeg through wine. It seems to work fine.

**Python wine wrapper:**

I have written the following python wrapper which must be

- placed in the same directory as `ffmpeg.exe`,
- given execution permissions and
- symlinked to /usr/bin/wineffmpeg.

Source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import sys
import os

#Robust against: ln ... --symbolic
base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
ffmpegbin = os.path.join(base_dir, 'ffmpeg.exe')

def wine_path(path):
    return subprocess.check_output(['winepath', '-w', path]).strip()

for i in range(1, len(sys.argv)):
    if sys.argv[i][:8].lower() == 'linpath:':
        sys.argv[i] = wine_path(sys.argv[i][8:].strip())

subprocess.call(['wine', ffmpegbin]+sys.argv[1:])
```

It passes all the commandline parameters verbatim, except if you give it a parameter in the form of `linpath:/linux/path/to/x`. It then converts it to `Z:\wine\path\to\x`. This would rarely be necessary though, since relative paths (which is most often used) denoted by `/` seems to work fine out of the box.

**Here is a succesful run:**

```
wineffmpeg -i "1-02 Ein Junge überlebt.mp3" -
filter:a "atempo=2.0"  -vn "converted/music.mp3"
ffmpeg version N-69672-g078be09 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 18.100 / 54. 18.100
  libavcodec     56. 21.102 / 56. 21.102
  libavformat    56. 19.100 / 56. 19.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5.  9.104 /  5.  9.104
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mp3, from '1-02 Ein Junge ├╝berlebt.mp3':
  Duration: 00:05:22.20, start: 0.034531, bitrate: 57 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 32000 Hz, mono, s16p, 57 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : LAME3.96r
fixme:msvcrt:MSVCRT__wsopen_s : pmode 0x01b6 ignored
Output #0, mp3, to 'converted/music.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf56.19.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 32000 Hz, mono, s16p
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.21.102 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=     944kB time=00:02:41.06 bitrate=  48.0kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:944kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.023277%
```

Comment: No need to use Wine. Just get a [static build of `ffmpeg`](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) for Linux.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard awesome thanks! Please tell me there are static builds of VLC as well...

Comment: I'm unsure about that, but you can refer to [Howto: Compile the development version of vlc under the latest Ubuntu release](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2141949).